# MS365 + Hybrid Exchange Distribution Group Oddness?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-365

So, one of the companies I work with encountered some chaos in their hybrid MS365 / on-prem deployment.

There is a distribution list (we'll call it `distlist1@example.com`) which is present on both the on prem and MS365 side of management consoles.  However, while on-prem Exchange control panel shows `distlist1` as accepting mail from both inside and outside the organization, MS365 has decided to ignore that and ONLY accept mail from 'internal' to the company.

As a result, `distlist1` used to receive invoices, etc. for one specific team is getting email rejections and not receiving its mail.

This is unable to be changed on the MS365 side of things, and LOOKS like some kind of disconnect or desync between Exchagne on-prem and MS365.

I'm not sure where to begin looking as to what could cause this on MS365 but if anyone has any pointers of where to look next and fix this so on MS365 it actually accepts the on-prem setting of "allow all to send to list" that'd be wonderful.

Comment: `1`. Toggle the setting on the on prem object. Initiate an Azure AD Connect delta sync. Wait an hour. Toggle the setting back on the on prem object. Initiate an Azure AD Connect delta sync. Wait an hour. `2.` If the steps in #1 fail to resolve the issue then open a support case from the tenant. It's free and they'll help resolve the issue. `3.` Do people know that Office 365 support is always free of charge? I find a lot of people that don't seem to know that. Maybe Microsoft should do a better job of making that known.

Comment: @joeqwerty no we didn't know that, but we're trying NOT to have to call Microsoft and stay on hold for the next 50 years :P  I've been told to leave stuff alone this weekend, so I'll poke this on Monday.

Comment: I get it. People have anecdotal stories about poor support from Microsoft. I've never experienced that myself. Make note that Office 365 support is provided by a completely separate group than MS product technical support. Office 365 support will usually contact you within 15-30 minutes of your opening a support ticket. Their follow up is stellar. I've received nothing short of exceptional support from the Office 365 support team.

Comment: Trying to solve a problem on your own is admirable. At some point though, it's counterproductive. None of us are born with any knowledge of anything. We learn by doing **AND** by asking. Don't be one of those people that let's a problem linger to the detriment of the business because they're too proud to reach out for help. I'm not saying you are one, I'm just saying don't be one.

Comment: @joeqwerty yep, that's why I reached out here to ask.  That, and sometimes things are more easily solved by the 'community' rather than Microsoft, who still refuse to acknowledge something as simple as "Failure to parse RFC Compliant messages when submitted via direct SMTP from Python" - which i had a separate open question on until I fixed it with a 'workaround'.  One reason I try and *avoid* Microsoft support when I can.  :)

Comment: @joeqwerty that worked perfectly flipping it and letting it resync.  Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad that worked. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle the setting on the on premises object. Initiate an Azure AD Connect delta sync. Wait an hour. Toggle the setting back on the on premises object. Initiate an Azure AD Connect delta sync. Wait an hour.

Comment: This actually worked.  I didn't believe it would initially, but it did!  Thanks!